# How to implement ScrollView in cocoa app?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, scrollview

I'm trying to add ScrollView to my app. But when I place it to the window and add some objects inside, it doesn't scroll! What should I do to make it work?

**Link to image:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcLCn.png

*-> three buttons inside the ScrollView, while one of them is outside of the window's bounds*

Comment: Which view did you enlarge to place the button outside the window?

Comment: Are there any constraints set up inside the view that force it to resize? When the view that holds your buttons is bigger than the clipView, your scrollView will scroll

Comment: @mangerlahn, tnx! I didn't add a Custom View inside the Clip View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the height of the contentSize of the scrollview larger than the height of the scrollview so that the scrollview can scroll vertically.To let the button outside the window be shown,the height of the contentSize should be larger than the maxY of the button